# Codeigneitor Error : Call to a member function result() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

im trying get results through a for loop.but i am getting above error.what can be the reason?.I have db named news. it contains columns as id,title,description.

My controller

```
class news extends CI_Controller
{
    function  __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    function index(){

        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $this->data['NewsData'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $this->load->view('site/cms/news',$this->data);
    }

}
```

Model

```
class news_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(); // Construct CI's core so that you can use it
        $this->load->database();

    }

     function get_news(){


        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('news');
        $news_details = $this->db->get();
        return $news_details;
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php if($NewsData->result() > 0){
                    foreach($NewsData->result() as $add){?>
<p><?php echo $add->title; ?></p>

 <?php }} ?>
```

Comment: The error message is very specific about the reason. You tried to call the method result() on null instead of an object. In other words: $NewsData is null. Find out why.

Comment: Always check if you have results or not. If not don't loop through the results or display an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Please correct your code using from below line.

```
<?php if($NewsData->num_rows() > 0){
       foreach($NewsData->result() as $add){?>
           <p><?php echo $add->title; ?></p>

       <?php }
} ?>
```